# How can I override an anchor element's font color when applying an active class to its parent li element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar with three buttons which I'm trying to highlight when they're active by applying "active" class to the `li` elements using jQuery - the border and font color are supposed to change. So far, only the border color changes while the text remains the same.

Also, I'd like to override or prevent  the `:hover` pseudo class when the link is active.

Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/Crankeedoodledoo/pen/XKOgGp) which will hopefully make this clearer. 
Could you please advise how to override the `a` element's font color?

Thanks!

Comment: You just have to be more specific with the styles, as in `li.active a {color : red}`

Comment: http://codepen.io/adeneo/pen/pbGAjb

Comment: @adeneo That keeps the initial style as well i.e. doubles the border. When I removed the border style from the code you added, it changed the font color but not the border .

Comment: You really can't figure out how to set the border for the LI, and the color for the anchor ? -> **http://codepen.io/adeneo/pen/WxPEAv**

Comment: Nope, I'm completely new at this so no need for the attitude. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: No attitude really, just asking, hence the questionmark, and I did provide you with the answer in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have HTML looking like

```
<ul class="topnav">

    <li class="topnavli">
      <a href="#fun-stop">Link 3</a>                                   
    </li>

     .......
```

Then styles for the anchors

```
.topnav a { color: #fff; }
```

then you add the active class to the LI elements, but the styles are only set as

```
.active { color: #FFADA0;  }
```

That's just styling the LI element, not the anchors inside, and the specification states that by default an anchor tag does not inherit attributes like color from the parent element if a `href` attribute is present, so those styles must be set directly on the anchor with something like

```
li.active a { color: #FFADA0; }
```

As the border is set on the LI element, that should be changed with a specific style for that element, so you end up with

```
li.active {
  border:3px solid #FFADA0; 
}

li.active a {   
   color: #FFADA0;     
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/adeneo/pen/WxPEAv)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.topnav .active a {  
    color: #FFADA0 ;     
}
```

```js
$('.topnav li').click(function() {
    $(".topnav li.active").removeClass("active");      
    $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

```css
.header h1 {   
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 44px;  
    letter-spacing: 3px;      
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    }

.topnav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;  
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;   
    background-color: #000; 
    z-index: 1;         
    }

.topnav li {   
    display: block;
    float: right;           
    margin: 20px 8px 0 0;  
    }


.topnavli {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
  }

.topnav li:first-child {
    margin-right: 50px;
}


.topnav li:hover {
    border: 3px solid #6fb7b7;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.topnav .active a {  
    color: #FFADA0 ;     
}
.topnav a {  
    display: block;
    color: #fff ;
    font-weight: 600;  
    padding: 10px 0 ;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; 
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;     
    width: 120px;   
    }

.topnav a:hover {
    color: #6fb7b7;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: 0.3s;  
}

.active {   
   color: #FFADA0 ;     
   border:3px solid #FFADA0; 
  }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">      
    <ul class="topnav">
      
        <li class="topnavli">
          <a href="#fun-stop">Link 3</a>                                   
        </li>
        <li class="topnavli"><a href="#projects">Link 2</a></li>
        <li class="topnavli"><a href="#home">Link 1</a></li>
        
        <h1>website</h1>                       
      </ul>     
    </div>
```